# Using Jmeter, how to launch Amazon S3 to verify files exist and also count the number of files?

Tags: jmeter

I'm pretty new to Jmeter and my task is to upload a bulk file to FTP and immediately launch AmazonS3 and verify the count of individual files generated using Jmeter and then launch an internal url and verify the same files are present in a particular folder

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate your scenario using Java code instead of Jmeter and then use Amazon AWS SDK's Methods in Java.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html